# Django flash messages showing only on the django admin page and not on the template

Tags: python, html, django

I have a login form and just want to display a confirmation message as soon as the user logs in. The message is being displayed, but it is displayed on the django admin page and not on the template(the web page visible to the user). I have checked almost everything like importing messages from django.contrib, checking the installed apps list, middleware list, context_processors. I don't know where am I going wrong or what am I missing. Please help!

My views.py function

```
def login_method(request):
    loginusername = request.POST['loginusername']
    loginpass = request.POST['loginpass']
    user = authenticate(username=loginusername, password=loginpass)
    if user is not None:
        auth_login(request, user)
        messages.success(request, "Successfully Logged In!")
        return redirect("appHome")
    else:
        messages.error(request, "Invalid Credentials, Please try again!")
        return redirect("home")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add this piece of code in your template where you want to display the messages:

```
    {% if messages %}
        {% for message in messages %}
                <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}">{{ message }}</div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
```

and also make sure you've add `'django.contrib.messages'` to your `INSTALLED_APPS`

Comment: Thanks a lot mate! It worked. I am learning django  and trying to explore the features. Missed the HTML part. Thanks once again! Take care!

Comment: No problem man! can you accept my answer please ? thanks!

Comment: Absolutely dude! This is my first post on stackoverflow, didnt know there is something like this. Done